# (Vue.js + VUEX) Commit inside Action promise not running

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have an action that returns a promise (so I can have a loading state on my Component)

For some reason the commit is not being triggered, nothing is run after the commit line, no errors as well

This is my action:

```
add({ commit }, data ) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {       
        axios.post('/spaces',data).then(
            response => {   
                commit('ADD_SPACE',response.data);  
                //this line only runs if put before the commit.
                resolve(response.data);
            },
            error => {                  
                reject(error);          
            }); 
    });
}
```

The mutation:

```
    ADD_SPACE (state, space) {
        state.spaces.push(space);         
    }
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your action, can you show the `ADD_SPACE` mutation and how you are dispatching the action in your component

Comment: if you `console.log(response.data)` in success callback , what are you getting?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I get the object with no problem. If I put the resolve before the commit, my view gets the 'response' and updates it (stop showing the load state), but the ADD_SPACE seems to never be run properly

Comment: that seems wierd!

Comment: With-out seeing more of your code it's difficult to say what's wrong. Maybe a  typo at your constant `export const ADD_SPACE = 'ADD_SPACE';` or commit method unpacking isn't working as expected (check `console.log(commit)` to see if it's the commit method - or you could remove the unpacking {} and access it with context.commit) or if you're using vuex store modules it could be a namespace issue. Just some ideas...

Comment: @Awolf does the answer I posted now something related with the unpacking thing? I was console.logging the commit object inside the functions to be sure and everything seemed ok. Quite weird.

Answer (score 0):

changing the action to be **async** and have an **await**, instead of creating the "new Promise" myself, solved the issue. Now the commit is actually executed (even though no errors were emitted on the first version + errors would be emitted if I changed the name of the commit to something invalid )

```
 async add({ commit }, space ) {
    return await axios.post('/spaces',space).then(
        response => {   
            commit('ADD_SPACE',response.data);    
            Promise.resolve(response.data);                
        },
        error => {                  
            Promise.reject(error);          
        });         
},
```

If anyone has a explanation to this tho, as I didn't understand the reason completely.